# Как сохранить favicon ico 24 bit?

Tags: html, icon, photoshop, favicon

Как сохранить favicon ico 24 bit? Пробовал через photoshop, но сохраняет 32 bit. Перепробовал несколько программ. И онлайн тоже. Нигде не сохраняет 24 bit, только 32 bit - в свойствах файла информация. В интернете подробного описания не нашел.

Comment: http://www.telegraphics.net/sw/icoformat.ru.html

Comment: Спасибо. Плагин я давно установил. Но не сохраняет ico 24 bit.  Только 32 bit

Comment: Как вот сохранить в фотошопе ico чтобы было 24 bit а не 32 bit?

Comment: 24-бит - это изображение без прозрачности. Удаляете альфа-канал, сохраняете в ico - получаете 24-битный ico. Прозрачности при этом, естественно, уже не будет. Но раз заказчику так нужно - это его проблемы.

Answer (score -1):

В png 24 bit тупо поменял расширение файла на ico. Получилось ico 24 bit.

Comment: Так.. ради интереса... А зачем?

Comment: Согласен, изменение расширения файла, не меняет его заголовков внутри файла :) любая программа умеющая читать такие файлы, читает не расширение файла, а внутренности, так что изменение ничего не поменяло... Только в заблуждение ввело. Равносильно изменить Avi на mp4, и думать, почему не применилось сжатие каким либо кодеком...

Comment: Заказчик заказал ico 24 bit. Но я потратил целый день на поиски информации. Ничего конкретного не нашел. И как заказ сдавать? Вот и поменял расширение. И тут как вижу ничего полезного не посоветуют)

Comment: Как вот сохранить в фотошопе ico чтобы было 24 bit а не 32 bit?